# Unable to find custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I developed a jQuery plugin in myPlugin.js as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

        var defaults = {};

        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            this.sayHello = function () {
                alert('Hello!');
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am calling the `sayHello()` method from another file call.js as follows:

```
myPlugin.sayHello();
```

Both myPlugin.js and call.js are included in my HTML file. When the compiler comes to the line `myPlugin.sayHello();` it reports an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myPlugin is not defined`.

What is the problem with my code?

UPDATE

I found a solution. I had in my code on one place initialized a plugin on a specific element, for ex. `$('#someElement').myPlugin();`. I just needed to invoke a plugin function with `someElement.sayHello();` and that worked.

The other solution is as @antyrat suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

        var defaults = {};

        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            this.sayHello = function () {
                alert('Hello!');
            };
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$( 'body' ).myPlugin();
console.log($( 'body' ))
$( 'body' )[0].sayHello();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have extended jQuery object by using `fn` shortcut ( `prototype` ). So you need to call your plugin as jQuery method:

```
$.myPlugin.sayHello();
```

---

Update

From what I see from your code, if you want to call `sayHello` function, you need to initialize it on some element, for example:

```
$( 'body' ).myPlugin();
```

And then call your method:

```
$( 'body' )[0].sayHello();
```

`[0]` we need because of `this.sayHello = function () {` refer to DOM Element, not to jQuery

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. It shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined`

Comment: @kiriz have you tried to call it on some elements? `$( 'body' ).myPlugin.sayHello();`

Comment: I did, it says `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The same error is for `$( 'body' ).myPlugin().sayHello();`.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this time the code `$( 'body' ).myPlugin();` made a total chaos - producing about 100 errors in second reported in jquery files. Had to terminate my browser through Task manager

Comment: @kiriz have you tried to run my code snippet? It works well for me. Or your code is different. Can you make jsFiddle demo or something?

Comment: yeah now I see your code snippet is working...Actually my code is more complex but I made it simple so I can put it as a question, but the principle with my real code and the one i provided is the same...Or looks to me to be the same. The thing is I have in my real code 2 code snippets that looks to me they are the same, but one is working and the other is not. So I put the question here to solve my non working one. Probably I'm missing something in my real code...but I don't know what.